# jQuery not selecting based on sub-element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify this code, such that, it does not select rows that have the child `<td colspan="12">`

```
$('#my-table tbody>tr').hide();
```

I've tried this:

```
$('#my-table tbody>tr:not(tr>td[colspan="12"])').hide();
```

and several similar variations with small tweaks, but I can't get the syntax right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :has():

```
$('#my-table tbody>tr:not(:has(td[colspan=12]))').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more flexibility or a more complex condition than @roasted's answer, you can use `.filter()`:

```
$('#my-table tbody>tr').filter(function() {
  return $(this).children('td[colspan="12"]').length === 0;
}).hide();
```